# Well synchronized dual camera system

Tags: camera, streaming-video

I want to create a high quality dual camera setup which then I want to stream to VR gogles. The important part is to have it well synchronized. I was going to use your Stereo Camera HAT from ArduCAM, however it is hardly available in my country and one of the shop that is selling it told me that there are some problems if the module is used with two separate cameras (I need to have them separated because I want the spacing between them to be adjustable). 
Afterwards I found out that the Compute Module ha two MIPI ports and it made me wonder could I use it without the HAT module? Can two cameras in different MIPI ports be well synchronized? I also need the system to have as low latency as possible and maybe without the HAT in between cameras and Raspberry the latency would be better?
Initially I’d like to have at least 1080p at 60 fps and 110-120 angle (I’m afraid that higher resolution would be to much data for constant streaming).

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you´re still interested, there you basically have three options

1. Take your chances with the Stereo HAT.
   Overall, this should be able to get you the closest to your aims, but there are two pitfalls that I´m aware of. Firstly, as you have pointed out, the soldering of the oscillator can be tricky. Secondly, I do not know what sort of framerate can realistically be reached using the HAT. If you look at Arducams demonstration video and slow down the playback speed, you´ll see that in that video at least, the framerate if very low. Even if neither the software, nor the HAT are bottlenecks, there is still the small matter that only the v3 Raspberry Pi camera is capable of 1080p60 if used on its own. So you would need to lower your requirements with regards to framerate and/or resolution even with this (according to me) best presently possible solution.
2. Get a USB-stereocamera
   Since the Pi 4 uses USB 3 this should still have too small a bandwith for your full requirements, but it might at least be bearable. In my opinion for you still a very unsatisfactory solution, but at least the Hardware would work.
3. Look into StereoPi https://stereopi.com/
   Since I don´t know much about this, I will just point out it´s existence and leave it at that.

In conclusion, you probably won´t be able to reach your requirements w.r.t framerate and resolution without some dirty tricks like super resolution. Still, what I would recommend is for you to get the Stereo HAT as a bundle with the v2 camera and see how far you can take that. If successful, I´d only then get seperate cameras.